# maven site folder isn't created in the src directory

Tags: maven, directory

This is my second Maven project. I want to create a site, so I executed the mvn site goal.
But the problem is, that no site folder exists in the src directory.
Certainly a site folder exists in the target directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in Maven which is located in `src/**` folder is assumed to be source code. If you want to create content than `src/site` is the correct location. The `target/site` area is the location where the resulting page will be generated into via `mvn site`.

The following is an example of what you can [create in your src/site area](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html).

```
+- src/
   +- site/
      +- apt/
      |  +- index.apt
      |
      +- fml/
      |  +- general.fml
      |  +- faq.fml
      |
      +- xdoc/
      |  +- other.xml
      |
      +- site.xml
```

I would suggest to start with a simple approach like:

```
+- src/
   +- site/
      +- apt/
      |  +- index.apt
      |
      +- site.xml
```

Starting with a [simple site descriptor (site.xml)](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html) you can take this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <menu name="First">
      <item name="Index" href="index.html" />
    </menu>
    ...
  </body>
  ...
</project>
```

And of course you should have some real content in [the index.apt](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html)

```
------
Title
------
------
Date
------

Section title

* Sub-section title

** Sub-sub-section title

*** Sub-sub-sub-section title

**** Sub-sub-sub-sub-section title
```